# Query out first 3 digits of a number field of a column

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a table, country:

```
loctn | area  | people
abc   | 12345 | 153465
cxv   | 43566 | 388573
```

I am looking for an output of the select query like:

```
select area, people from Country where loctn='abc' 

loctn | area | people
abc   | 123  | 153
```

Comment: Are you sure you want the first three digits, not (based on your example) the area/100 and the population/1000 ? Maybe you could add examples with numbers of other magnitudes to clarify.

Comment: actually I want to append last 3 digits with K+ for a number filed ie, if its 12345 it should be 12K+ , for 134567 its should be 134K+

Comment: So `K+` denotes thousands? Your comment doesn't match what you showed in the question...

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51596892/edit) to clarify what you are really trying to do, with more examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your comments you actually do want to divide by 1000. You can truncate or get the floor value so it's an integer - e.g. `floor(area/1000)` - and then concatenate a fixed string value if you want.

```
-- sample data as a CTE
with country (loctn, area, people) as (
  select 'abc', 12345, 153465 from dual
  union all select 'cxv', 43566, 388573 from dual
  union all select 'xyz', 134567 , 1234567  from dual
)
-- actual query
select loctn,
  floor(area/1000) || 'K+' as area,
  floor(people/1000) || 'K+' as people
from country;

LOCTN AREA       PEOPLE    
----- ---------- ----------
abc   12K+       153K+     
cxv   43K+       388K+     
xyz   134K+      1234K+
```

or for a single value kind of like the query in your question:

```
select loctn,
  floor(area/1000) || 'K+' as area,
  floor(people/1000) || 'K+' as people
from country
where loctn = 'abc';

LOCTN AREA       PEOPLE    
----- ---------- ----------
abc   12K+       153K+
```

This matches the output you described in comments (I think) rather than what you showed in the question, but it's still unclear what you really want.

Answer (score 0):

Are area and people numeric fields ?

If yes try query below. Else remove to_char from query and run.

```
select loctn,
       substr(to_char(area),1,3) as area,
       substr(to_char(people),1,3)  as people 
from Country
```

Comment: I think it does not make sense to extract the first 3 digits of a number.

Comment: i agree. But if that's the requirements we can go with this option.

Comment: I think first a meaningful question should be posed that contains all  relevant information and then  an answer to this question should be posted.

Comment: Hi Tinu, Thanks, that worked.. actually am planning on appending the last 3 digits with K+ . am able to achieve that with the above query for 6 digit numbers.  For numbers greater or less than 6, how should the query be modified. or is it a different query?